# Select rows within an overlapping range based on another column in R tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like this: 
the col1 defines the start of a range when the direction is " **+** " while the col2 establishes the beginning of a range when the direction is " **-** ".

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1=c(1,10,100,40,1000), col2=c(15,20,50,80,2000), 
             direction=c("+","+","-","+","+"), score=c(50,100,300,10,300))
df 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>    col1  col2 direction score
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1     1    15 +            50
#> 2    10    20 +           100
#> 3   100    50 -           300
#> 4    40    80 +            10
#> 5  1000  2000 +           300
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

By considering the direction, I want to extract from the rows with overlapping ranges the ones with the highest score.

I want my data to look like this.

```
#>    col1  col2 direction score
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1    10    20 +           100
#> 3   100    50 -           300
#> 5  1000  2000 +           300
```

Any ideas and help are highly appreciated.

Comment: row 5 is retained even though it doesn't overlap with any?  Also, what if you have another row (say row 6) with range `1,7,+` and score `4`, would row 1 and 2 both be retained? because row1 would overlap with row 6, but exceed its score, and row 2 would overlap with row1 but exceed its score?

Comment: -row 5 is retained even though it doesn't overlap with any?
> yes exactly needs to be maintained because it is not overlapping. <br>
-with range ```1,7,+``` and score ```4``` 
> This has not been seen in the data, but it's an excellent point. I keep again the 
```10,20, +```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `slice_max` after grouping by `rleid` on the 'direction'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(direction)) %>%
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = score) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
   col1  col2 direction score
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1    10    20 +           100
2   100    50 -           300
3  1000  2000 +           300
```